# how to restrict cross web application search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, 2016, web-application

I have several web application in SharePoint 2016.  Now if any site collection admin add search result web part, by default is show result from other web application as well.

I want to change the search setting to be limited to current site collection only.  How can I achieve it !

Answer (score 1):

- Edit Search Results Page
- Edit the Search Results Web Part.
- In the `Web Part tool pane`, in the `Search Criteria` section, click `Change query`.
- On the `BASICS` tab > At `Query Text` > add the below query to scope the search results for one web application based on its URL.

  ```
  {?{searchTerms} PATH://yourwebapplicationURL}
  ```

For more details check [Configure properties of the Search Results Web Part in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549987(v=office.16).aspx)

---

**[Update]**

You have the following options

1. Create a `Query rule` with a `block result` with the above query, check the details steps at [Manage query rules in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj871676(v=office.16).aspx)
2. Create a `Search Result Source` in the site collection and use it in your search web part.

   - Site collection setting >  Site Collection Administration > Search Result Source > add the above query.
   - in your search result web part, use this search result source.

Comment: thanks, but I guess the solution you suggested is need to be done at each search result webpart.  Instead I want that all webpart will by default search with in the current site collection

Comment: Please check the updated answer!